# Looping in ArrayList isn't working (Get() method)

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm looking for days something to help me, but I didn't find anything for this problem and I really don't know what to do.

Here is the problem... I'm trying to get the url I added in this `ArrayList (urlPage)` in the position i inside my loop, but I got this compilation error: Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final. I've tried many things, but nothing works.

```
/* Create a loop starting with 0 and ending with 3 to add all the components into the panel */
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            productIconLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
            productIconLabel[i].addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + urlPage.get(i));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }  
                }
            });
```

The code in the loop continues (there's why here there's no end bracket to for), but this is the part that I'm having problems with.
This is the function where I add the `url` into the `ArrayList`.

```
/* Function to receive part of information sent from the form page */
    public void radioButtonResult(int productIndexNumber, String productImageAddress, String productName, double productPrice, String url) {
        productIconLabel[productIndexNumber].setIcon(new ImageIcon(productImageAddress));
        productNameLabel[productIndexNumber].setText(productName);
        productPriceLabel[productIndexNumber].setText(Double.toString(productPrice) + " €");
        urlPage.add(productIndexNumber, url);
    }
```

The only problem is the compilation error. To make some tests I've changed i for 0, 1 and 2 and its worked. I appreciate any help.

Comment: which line in the code gives you error?

Comment: is the radioButtonResult function part of your getRuntime().exec ?

Comment: Is this one: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + urlPage.get(i))

Comment: You're in new MouseAdapter(), so it doesn't know the variable i.
Make it final.

Comment: No, this radioButtonResult is a different function, I just put in here to show how I'm adding things in my ArrayList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in new MouseAdapter(), so it doesn't know the variable i. Different scope.

Use a final variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
            final int currentIter = i;
            productIconLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
            productIconLabel[i].addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    try {
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + urlPage.get(currentIter));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: Great ! Glad we could help

Answer (score 2):

`i` needs to be final in order to access it inside of a method of an anonymous inner class. You can do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) {
        final int fi = i;
        productIconLabel[i] = new JLabel("");
        productIconLabel[i].addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + urlPage.get(fi));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
      .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use local variable `i` in an anonymous inner class. Because those 2 scopes are different.